# Cannot make image center vertically

Tags: html, css

The image is not centering vertically despite code which I have used. I have checked most of the possibilities for why it is not working, but I am unsure and in need of assistance.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="website-1">
    <a href="">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/17/58/sample-815141_960_720.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); left:50%; transform: translateX(-50%); width:50%">
    </a>
  <div class="arrow3 bounce">
    <a href="#video"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#ED4C67;" ></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#website-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kLvjw5k1/3/)

The issue was you used transform twice. So only the second one got rendered.

You need to do it like so:

```
transform:translate(50%,-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea that was a thing, thanks for the help.